# Assigning each property of every single item of IEnumerable Collection to different textboxes

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, lambda

Elaboration of what I want to achieve :

I have an collection of an object in my itemsource.Suppose there are three items in my itemsource and i want each property of every single item to be assigned to different textboxes, how can i get this ?

```
textbox1.text = // assign the first value of an item to this

textbox2.text = // assign the second value of an item to this
```

Comment: What was the reason to downvote a perfectly asked question?

Comment: @VoodooChild, I wasn't the person that downvoted this, but there doesn't seem to be a question! We can only make assumptions as to what kind of lambda expression Malcolm wants if that's what he actually wants.

Comment: Perfectly asked question? There is no question.

Comment: @Marius Schulz if it was not a perfect question the answers would not have been there. Anyways cheers for  u r down vote .. :)

Comment: @Malcolm: It's sometimes possible to *guess* at the meaning of a question even when it's badly written... as this one certainly is.

Comment: @Malcolm: Oh, it was not my down vote, although I thought about adding a second one ...

Comment: @Jon Skeet the probelm was not with a down vote . If the person is down voting something he should leave an comment to say why it was down voted so that the person who asked the question can correct it or write in a correct format so that this question would help others.:)

Comment: @Marius Schulz sorry for doubting you man ..Appolgies..:)

Comment: @Malcolm: I didn't mention voting. You claimed that it must be a perfect question, because there were answers. I was just saying that that is a logical fallacy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
textbox1.Text = enumerable.First();
textbox2.Text = enumerable.Skip(1).First();
```

Comment: I think you could also do. `enumerable.ElementAt(0)`, `enumerable.ElementAt(1)`, etc.

Comment: Where's the lambda expression? ;)

Answer (score 3):

Why would you need a lambda?

```
var itemSource = enumerable.toList();
textbox1.text = itemSource[0].toString();
textbox2.text = itemSource[1].toString();
```

Comment: I agree, I also do not find using lambda suitable in this case.

Comment: As i was using the foreach loop earlier and i had to replace it with an better option so just knew that lambda expression would make it easier instead of getting looped the enumerable list again and again. tx for the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way to skin this cat:

```
textbox1.Text = itemSource.ElementAtOrDefault(0);
textbox2.Text = itemSource.ElementAtOrDefault(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put your text boxes into a list and step through both the items source and the text box list.

```
var textBoxes = new List<TextBox> { textbox1, textbox2 };
for( int index = 0; index < itemsSource.Count; index++ )
{
    textBoxes[index].Text = itemsSource[index].ToString();
}
```

I'm not sure what a lambda expression would do for you. Could you expand your question?